# Finding the value of a point in 3D domain depending on neighboring points

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, vectors, 3d, multigrid

I have some data on 3D models of soil's moisture content, the model is in the finite-element grid. I have converted the program outputs to a table in four columns x, y, z, Theta where Theta is the moisture content. I want to take cross sections from the 3D domain in some specific positions (section ABCD in the figure). I want to calculate the value of Theta in a 5*5 grid in the cross-section, but the points around each node of the grid are not coplanar with the unknown point. I did this before for 2D domains but the 3D domains seem more complicated for me.

I wonder if someone could help me with a method to calculate the moisture of point P0 depending on some neighboring points P1, P2, ...
[image: figure of the 3D domain]

Comment: Ok, what's the question? You need some way to interpolate to get the value of $P_0$, and you are asking people to list a lot of interpolation method for you to pick the best one. That is too broad.

Comment: @user202729 I am not specialized in math, so please guide me to some simple methods, to implement them in python code.

Comment: Anyway this is not a good fit for Math.SE because there is no definite way to tell if an answer is better than other - it's subjective/opinion-based. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpolation) lists at least 5 methods. For "nice" data even take the average of them is sufficiently good.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer to my question.
The answer is to used Gridded interpolation like [the Kriging method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kriging) or any similar [nD interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_interpolation) especially the [trilinear interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trilinear_interpolation).

I have posted an implementation in `python` on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47902153/5820024) page at StackOverflow.

Hope everyone benefits from it.

Best regards